# How to get power consumption from datasheet

Tags: power-supply, datasheet, stepper-motor, calculation

I am using this [stepper motor](https://www.haydonkerkpittman.com/products/linear-actuators/hybrid-stepper/size-11-double-stack) on my project and am trying to pick a power supply that will be able to supply enough current to all of my components. Looking at the [datasheet](https://www.haydonkerkpittman.com/-/media/ametekhaydonkerk/downloads/data-sheets/haydon-28000-ds-data.pdf?la=en&revision=c62348ea-55cd-4d76-b053-eee136ffe5be) I'm not sure whether to use the current/phase or the power input value as a basis for how much current it will pull. What's the difference between these two? It's getting an input voltage of 24VDC [image: datasheet]

Comment: Get a supply that produces the voltage and can supply the current. Also, note there are three motors listed there with different winding voltages in case you did not notice. The problem with using the power rating is that a supply that produces .313V and can supply 12A will produce the same power required to run the motor with the 12V winding. But it won't be in the form the motor needs.

Comment: It's available with 3 different windings. If you don't already know which you have, use an ohmmeter to find out first.

Comment: If your power supply is 24VDC, but your motors are 12V/5V/3.3V then they will try to work *multiple times harder* than they are designed to, and likely fail.  It may be best if you can find motors designed for 24V.

Comment: It depends on your driver. The lower voltage windings have less inductance but require more current. A modern switching type driver will control the current when driven by a 24V supply. The driver itself needs to be able to handle the required current - many have an adjustment or switches to set the current. Your power supply needs to be able to supply that current and a bit more for loss etc. You’re better off with a psu that has more current than what you need as opposed to not enough. Eg. If the motor needs 2A, then a 6A psu might be a good choice. Maybe 10A - depending on size, cost etc.

Comment: The actual power consumption is shown as 7.5W. That is probably a thermal limitation. Your power supply will have to have the required current rating and that means the Wattage is the psu will be much greater.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/200324/how-to-interpret-the-stepper-motor-voltage-requirement/200328#200328

Answer (score 0):

- 7.5 W is average max power base on temp rise. But you can easily draw double this power for bursts of acceleration if you can limit the duration and average power.  You may also want to add a 50 mm fan to each motor if plan on using max power.
- Likewise max power rating on supplies is base on maximum junction temperature and you may want to choose force air cooling addon unlike you add a conservative 25% to 50% power margin to the capacity rating to improve the MTBF by reducing the temp rise or peak currents of electrolytic capacitors
- But your choice also depends on brand-name recognition and quality of the design.